# Open VPN copying files very slow

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pfsense

This is my first experience with setting up a VPN.

I have Open VPN running at my work network on a firewall/router that uses the PFsense admin software.

I connected to the VPN from my home network successfully.

When I tried to copy a 500k file from a device on the remote network to my home computer it took a very long time (5 minutes or more). My internet connection is fast at both locations, so I'm not sure why this would be.

Is it because of the encryption, or some of the network settings? This is all pretty new to me.

Here is a link to the tutorial I followed.
https://www.highlnk.com/2013/12/configuring-openvpn-on-pfsense/

Also my home computer is a mac running the Viscosity OpenVPN client.

Comment: How long is very long ?

Comment: 5 minutes or more

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: How are you copying the file? Windows share? What's the ping time like to the remote network? Please try copying a file over http as well.

Comment: I was use smb:// the ping time is about 16ms

Comment: using afp:// it seems to be a lot faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use afp://x.x.x.x it works much faster than smb://x.x.x.x

under mac os finder > connect to server

Answer (score 0):

If you used UDP as your transport protocol, check the firewall(s) for UDP rate limiting or DoS thresholds.  Add rules or exceptions for the VPN traffic accordingly.

Also, try lowering MTU for the VPN connection to something that will allow for VPN encapsulation.  A value like 1300 should be more than adequate for testing purposes.

Comment: thanks, I checked and there is no rate limiting. 1500 is the default MTU for this router, does that sounds about right?

Comment: @mjr 1500 is largest allowed MTU for ethernet PDU.  Adding a VPN encapsulation layer will put the packet above 1500, which means it will have to be fragmented to be transmitted.  This results in performance loss.  Reduce MTU on VPN components to allow for encapsulation layer to be added while still keeping packet size <1500